# ¿Como reiniciar Kinect pragmáticamente?

Tags: c#

Me han pedido realizar algo simple en `kinect` pero en `C#` ( llevo 1 semana estudiando `C#` ya que no es mi lenguaje).

Gracias a los códigos que comparte Microsoft cuando instalas el SDK, tengo el código donde sale tu imagen de kinect y de fondo una imagen.

Alguien que controle `C#` o haya trabajado con `kinect` que puedo orientarme?

Tengo:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        // get the kinectSensor object
        this.kinectSensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();

        // open the reader for the depth frames
        this.bodyIndexFrameReader = this.kinectSensor.BodyIndexFrameSource.OpenReader();

        // wire handler for frame arrival
        this.bodyIndexFrameReader.FrameArrived += this.Reader_FrameArrived;

        this.bodyIndexFrameDescription = this.kinectSensor.BodyIndexFrameSource.FrameDescription;

        // allocate space to put the pixels being converted
        this.bodyIndexPixels = new uint[this.bodyIndexFrameDescription.Width * this.bodyIndexFrameDescription.Height];

        // create the bitmap to display
        this.bodyIndexBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(this.bodyIndexFrameDescription.Width, this.bodyIndexFrameDescription.Height, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);

        // set IsAvailableChanged event notifier
        this.kinectSensor.IsAvailableChanged += this.Sensor_IsAvailableChanged;

        // open the sensor
        this.kinectSensor.Open();

        // set the status text
        this.StatusText = this.kinectSensor.IsAvailable ? Properties.Resources.RunningStatusText
                                                        : Properties.Resources.NoSensorStatusText;

        // use the window object as the view model in this simple example
        this.DataContext = this;

        // initialize the components (controls) of the window
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //Inicializo el TIMER
         inicioTimer();

    }
```

Cuando se inicia la aplicación se abre un WPF con un objeto IMAGE donde aparece lo que muestra el KINECT, despues de que acabe el TIMER se inician una serie de métodos y necesito que vuelva a iniciarse el KINECT, a que método tendría que llamar de los que tengo en el MainWindow?

Gracias

Comment: Hola @FranPino. Por favor aclara más tu problema puntual. No solicites que alguien te ayude directamente en tu problema, para ese tipo de cosas existen sitios donde pagas a las personas para que hagan tu trabajo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto podría ayudar

```
public void StopKinect()
{
   if (this.sensor == null)
   {
       return;
   }

   if (this.sensor.SkeletonStream.IsEnabled)
   {
      this.sensor.SkeletonStream.Disable();
   }

   if (this.sensor.ColorStream.IsEnabled)
   {
      this.sensor.ColorStream.Disable();
   }

   if (this.sensor.DepthStream.IsEnabled)
   {
      this.sensor.DepthStream.Disable();
   }

   this.sensor.SkeletonFrameReady -= this.SensorSkeletonFrameReady;

   try
   {
      this.sensor.Stop()
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       Debug.WriteLine("Ha ocurrido un error {0}", e.Message)
   }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias creo que esto es lo que necesitaba